# Generate all ordered combinations of a list, where each combination includes all items

Tags: python, list, combinations

Whats the best way to generate all combinations of a list, where each combinations contains every item from the list and where you can combine other items.

For example, for a list `['a','b','c']`, I like to generate:

```
['a','b','c']
['ab','c']
['a','bc']
['abc']
```

I find it a bit similar to: [Python: Generating all ordered combinations of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581425/python-generating-all-ordered-combinations-of-a-list).  But this one only cares about the slices.  I want all the combinations that takes every item from the list.  Is there a built in function from itertools that can be used to generate the answer?

The list could also be numbers, that could have duplicates values.  For example: `[1,2,1]` should generate:

```
[1,2,1]
[12,1]
[1,21]
[121]
```

I could try to use the code from the link, but instead of generating combinations of the items, I would generate the combinations base on the index of the list. Where I take all combinations that start with 0, then look for the next item and look for all combinations that start with that item and so on.  I dont think that would be efficient though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of two adjacent characters in your string as being either "separated" or "concatenated". Using `itertools.product()` you can generate all combinations of separated/concatenated between two characters and then use a simple function to generate a list of strings from this information:

```
import itertools

l = ['a','b','c']

def generate_combination(source, comb):
    res = []
    for x, action in zip(source,comb + (0,)):
        res.append(x)
        if action == 0:
            yield "".join(res)
            res = []

print [list(generate_combination(l,c)) 
       for c in itertools.product((0,1), repeat=len(l)-1)]
```

This doesn't work for numbers though unless you convert them to strings first.

Comment: This seems to work fine.  Just trying to see how it works.

Comment: I just understood your generator function, its pretty cool.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is additional code to make  @acidtobi answer work for both `int` and `char` with the help of `.isdigit()`.

```
final = [list(generate_combination(l,c)) 
       for c in itertools.product((0,1), repeat=len(l)-1)]

print [[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in alist ] for alist in final]
```

So for  `l = [ 1,2,3]` , it will show

```
>>> 
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 23], [12, 3], [123]]
```

And for `l = ['a','b','c']`

```
>>> 
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'bc'], ['ab', 'c'], ['abc']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
l = ['a','b','c','d']
#l = [0,1,2,3]
d = np.arange(2**(len(l)-1))
#create a separator array for all possible combinations
sep = np.where((d[:,None] & (1 << np.arange(len(l))[::-1])) > 0, ',','')
#merge the separator to the strings
merged = np.core.defchararray.add(sep,np.asarray(l,dtype=str)).tolist()
#reformat and split
[''.join(e).split(',') for e in merged]

#works for any characters
[['abcd'],
 ['abc', 'd'],
 ['ab', 'cd'],
 ['ab', 'c', 'd'],
 ['a', 'bcd'],
 ['a', 'bc', 'd'],
 ['a', 'b', 'cd'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]

Out[128]: 
[['0123'],
 ['012', '3'],
 ['01', '23'],
 ['01', '2', '3'],
 ['0', '123'],
 ['0', '12', '3'],
 ['0', '1', '23'],
 ['0', '1', '2', '3']]
```