# Efficient way of calculating specific length combinations of adjacent data?

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools, combinatorics

I have a list of elements, of which I'd like to determine all possible combinations that can be arranged - preserving their order - to arrive at 'n' groups

So as an example, if I have an ordered list of A, B, C, D, E, and only want 2 groups, the four solutions would be;

```
ABCD, E
ABC, DE
AB, CDE
A, BCDE
```

Now, with some help from another [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726020/1170675) I've come up with a workable brute-force solution that calculates all possible combinations of all possible groupings from which I simply extract those cases that meet my target number of groupings.

For reasonable numbers of elements, this is just fine, but as I extend the numbers of elements, the number of combinations increases very very quickly, and I was wondering if there might be a clever way to limit the solutions calculated to only those that meet my target groupings number?

Code so far is as follows;

```
import itertools
import string
import collections

def generate_combination(source, comb):
    res = []
    for x, action in zip(source,comb + (0,)):
        res.append(x)
        if action == 0:
            yield "".join(res)
            res = []
            
#Create a list of first 20 letters of the alphabet
seq = list(string.ascii_uppercase[0:20])
seq
```

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T']

```
#Generate all possible combinations
combinations = [list(generate_combination(seq,c)) for c in itertools.product((0,1), repeat=len(seq)-1)]
len(combinations)
```

524288

```
#Create a list that counts the number of groups in each solution, 
#and counter to allow easy query
group_counts = [len(i) for i in combinations]
count_dic = collections.Counter(group_counts)
count_dic[1], count_dic[2], count_dic[3], count_dic[4], count_dic[5], count_dic[6]
```

(1, 19, 171, 969, 3876, 11628)

So as you can see, while over half a million combinations were calculated, if I had only wanted ones of length = 5, only 3,876 need have been calculated

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partition of `seq` into 5 parts is equivalent to a choice of 4 locations in `range(1, len(seq))` at which to cut `seq`. 
Thus you could use `itertools.combinations(range(1, len(seq)), 4)` to generate all the partitions of `seq` into 5 parts:

```
import itertools as IT
import string

def partition_into_n(iterable, n, chain=IT.chain, map=map):
    """
    Return a generator of all partitions of iterable into n parts.
    Based on http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576795/ (Raymond Hettinger)
    which generates all partitions.
    """
    s = iterable if hasattr(iterable, '__getitem__') else tuple(iterable)
    size = len(s)
    first, middle, last = [0], range(1, size), [size]
    getitem = s.__getitem__
    return (map(getitem, map(slice, chain(first, div), chain(div, last)))
            for div in IT.combinations(middle, n-1))

seq = list(string.ascii_uppercase[0:20])
ngroups = 5
for partition in partition_into_n(seq, ngroups):
    print(' '.join([''.join(grp) for grp in partition]))

print(len(list(partition_into_n(seq, ngroups))))
```

yields

```
A B C D EFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
A B C DE FGHIJKLMNOPQRST
A B C DEF GHIJKLMNOPQRST
A B C DEFG HIJKLMNOPQRST
...
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO P Q RS T
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO P QR S T
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO PQ R S T
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP Q R S T
3876
```